# NullPointer Exception when access Newly Merged Records JPA, Entity Manager

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I have Two Entities , Entity Applicants, Entity JobApplications. The Relationship is

```
    //Entity Applicants
    public class AppPers implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "appPers",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<JobApplications> jobApplicationsCollection;
    .........................
    }

    //Entity JobApplications
    public class JobApplications implements Serializable {
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_id", referencedColumnName = "APP_ID", insertable = false,         updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private AppPers appPers;
```

So after i do a merger

```
    AppPers ap =em.find(AppPers.class,appId);
    ap.setJobApplicationsCollection(c);
    em.merge(ap);
    em.refresh(ap);
```

And try to execute

```
    //fetch the newly created list
    List<JobApplications> list  = new ArrayList<JobApplications>();
    list = em.createNamedQuery("JobApplications.findAll").getResultList();
    //list size is 3 in my case
    for( JobApplications ja: list) {
    String a = ja.getAppPers().getSurName();
    }
```

surName being a column of AppPers, I get NullPointer Exception. This happens untill i restart Glassfish then the Null Pointer Does not Happen. I have tried setting the fetch to Eager but still no joy. What could i be missing

Comment: also, since your relationship is insertable=false, updatable=false, JPA's not going to process it correctly.  Those should be used when you use multiple bindings for a single column, e.g. many to many foreign keys.

Comment: thanx for your info,makes alot of sense will look for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this relates to JPA. It's plain old Java. You have a class defined as

```
public class JobApplications implements Serializable {
    private AppPers appPers;
    ...
}
```

The default value of a field is `null`.

So if you do

```
JobApplications ja = new JobApplications ();
AppPers ap = ja.getAppPers();
```

`ap` will be null. So if you do

```
JobApplications ja = new JobApplications ();
String a = ja.getAppPers().getSurName();
```

you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: loop through the collections of what? If you want us to find a bug in some code, show us the code which has a bug. Not some unrelated, different code.

Comment: list = em.createNamedQuery("JobApplications.findAll").getResultList();   for(JobApplications j : list){ String a = j.getAppPers().getsurName()}

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question. Make it clear. Show the real, relevant code. Tell us which parts are in separate transactions and which parts are in the same one.

Comment: Your code still creates a new JobApplications and expect to have its appPers field magically initialized. Do you understand what `new` means?

Comment: my bad..i meant to comment that out

Comment: Before the merge, do the job applications have a non-null appPers?